# Extract the integer value from the string

Tags: php, integer

I need to save integer value of the field "totalMinutes" into the corresponding field "tM" of the MySQL DB. How to extract the integer value from the string "totalMinutes"?

PHP:

```
totalMinutes = "0015"; // or totalMinutes = "0210", etc.
```

DB:

```
`tM` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: `intval($totalMinutes)`

Comment: `0015` is integer value.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar: I need to avoid 00

Comment: @KlausosKlausos You haven't said that in your question.

Comment: Please provide an example of exact output you need

Comment: Why is the `tM` field not a numeric field in the database to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the string as an `integer` directly in calculations for example, PHP is very forgiving when it comes to type casting. If your problem is that it outputs `0015` when you `echo` it or something just use `intval()` or even a simple `(int)` cast.

[Example](http://3v4l.org/BN2I5)

```
$intAsString = "0005";

echo $intAsString * 5;
echo "\n" . intval($intAsString);
echo "\n" . (int) $intAsString;
```

Outputs:

```
25
5
5
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT CAST(tM AS UNSIGNED) FROM TABLE
```

OR `intval($val)` with PHP

Answer (score 1):

Use `ltrim`

```
echo ltrim("0015", "0");
```

## Output

```
15
```

## Codepad

Answer (score 0):

simply type cast to integer it works faster than `intval()`

```
$totalMinutes =(int) "0015";
```